# How to place two input next to each other in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to place the text input and the button next to each other, with about 10px margin between them.

Whit this code, i get the result what you can see on the uploaded photo.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="float-left">
    <input type="number" class="form-control item_page_item_db w-50" id="quantity<?php echo intval($kat['termek_id']); ?>" value="1">
  </div>
  <div class="float-left">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary add_to_cart_button" data-product-id="<?php echo intval($kat['termek_id']); ?>" type="button"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket" aria-hidden="true"></i> Kosárba helyezem
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

I want them closer to each other, and vertically centered the right way. Now, they dont have any css for size, only just colors and font size...

Comment: Note that the `<link>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below structure and css. Hope it helps.

```css
.col-sm-6 input[type="number"]{width:100%}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="number" class="form-control item_page_item_db" id="quantity<?php echo intval($kat['termek_id']); ?>" value="1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary add_to_cart_button" data-product-id="<?php echo intval($kat['termek_id']); ?>" type="button"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket" aria-hidden="true"></i> Kosárba helyezem
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap way: Use `col` classes to create a width (Shown below)

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" value="1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i>
      Kosárba helyezem
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pure CSS way:

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
}

input {
  width: 100px !important; /**use specific width**/
  margin-right: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="cont">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" value="1">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i>
    Kosárba helyezem
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use col-md-6 class instead of float-left or right.

Comment: Why? That will give bigger space between them.